# XCode 7 : How to assemble armv7, arm64, and x86 .S files separately?

Tags: ios, xcode, assembly, arm64

I am porting an emulator project to iOS which includes some ARM and X86 machine code in .S files. How do I configure my project so that the ARM code is only compiled for real iOS hardware, and the X86 code is only compiled for the simulator.

Furthermore the ARM code I have is ARMv7, not ARM64. 
As far as I can see I should be able to put a ".machine armv7" directive into an ARM .S file to get the assembler to use the older instruction set (which should run fine on arm64, right?). However the assembler gives an error: "error: unknown directive .machine armv7".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the C preprocessor, which Xcode runs on assembly files by default:

```
file_x86_64.s:
#if defined __x86_64__
// x86_64 assembly code
#endif

file_armv7.s:
#if defined __arm__
// arm assembly code
#endif
```

etc.  You're right that armv7 code will run on arm64 devices, but it can't be linked into an arm64 executable, so you'll need to have a C implementation or arm64 assembly in order to build for arm64.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it working by creating separate targets for i386, x86_64, and armv7, and then adding them all as *optional* dependencies of the main target, but your way seems neater. Could I maybe put the armv7 code in a dynamic lib to get it running on arm64? Perhaps I should just bite the bullet and learn arm64...

Comment: @ReubenScratton: dynamic linking doesn't allow armv7 and arm64 code to interoperate.  You will probably want to bite the bullet.

Comment: Damn, I thought it'd be like arm vs thumb code. Does that mean only entire processes can be armv7 on arm64 h/w?